# How to get list data using Criteria Mongotemplate in Nested Object

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I want to get lists of data Review where `reviewer` object has `id = "mawar_merah2"`.

[image]

How to create a query using MongoTemplate in spring boot.

this is my query:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("reviewer").elemMatch(Criteria.where("id").is("mawar_merah2")));
List<Review> timeLinesReview = getMongoTemplate().find(query, Review.class); 
return timeLinesReview;
```

Comment: this is my query:

Query query = new Query();  
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("reviewer").elemMatch(Criteria.where("id").is("mawar_merah2")));
List<Review> timeLinesReview = getMongoTemplate().find(query, Review.class);
return timeLinesReview;

Comment: elemMatch is used with array fields - `reveiwer` is an object (or sub-document or embedded document). See [Query on sub (or embedded) document fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-exact-matches-on-embedded-documents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `reviewer.id` in query

Change

```java
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("reviewer").elemMatch(Criteria.where("id").is("mawar_merah2")));
```

To

```java
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("reviewer.id").is("mawar_merah2")));
```